# Docker doesn't see .env in dockerfile when trying to run Django collectstatic

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have multiple containers run in the order stated in docker-compose. In an app container, I need to execute file collectstatic. The thing is when I try to do it in dockerfile like that:

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic
```

it breaks down as it doesn't see env vars, although the file is declared in the docker-compose. When I omit that line (and lines in other containers that depend on it) and I log into the container and generate the files - everything runs smoothly.

How can I run it automatically?

```
version: '3.8'

services:

   db:
    container_name: postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/postgres/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./Dockerfiles/postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
      - ./Dockerfiles/postgres/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   web:
     container_name: django_app
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfiles/app/Dockerfile
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     working_dir: /app
     env_file:
         - .env
     volumes:
         - ./:/app/
     depends_on:
       - db

   nginx:
     container_name: django_nginx
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfiles/nginx/Dockerfile
     ports:
       - 1337:80
     working_dir: /app
     depends_on:
       - web
```

Comment: Show your docker-compose file

Comment: @MarkB I added docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the necessary environment variables in the Dockerfile before running the collectstatic command. You can use the ENV instruction in the Dockerfile to set environment variables.

```
# Set environment variables
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings
ENV DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@postgres/mydb

# Run collectstatic command
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

In the above example, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and DATABASE_URL are environment variables that are needed for collectstatic to run properly. You can replace these with the environment variables that your application requires.

Alternatively, you can also pass the environment variables as arguments to the docker run command when starting the container

Comment: unfortunately in my app you need a lot of variables and you set them up  before running docker, I want to automize it as much as I can, so you don't have to edit dockerfiles that are committed in git repository